# how to refresh a part of the page when configurable variation is selected in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, ajax, jquery, configurable-swatches

I want to reload a div section on the product detail page of the configurable product when the configurable variation is selected. How do I achieve that?

```
require(['jquery','jquery/ui'],function($){
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.swatch-option',function(){
        $('#points-refresh').load(document.URL +  ' #points-refresh');
    })
});
```

## points-refresh is the id of the div section I want to reload whenever I switch one configurable child product to another.

I have tried this. But this does not work. Can anyone tell me the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using a custom Module name "Company_MyModule"

**step 1)** 
Create **requirejs-config.js** under *app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/*

***File :  app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js***

```
var config = {
    config: {    
        mixins: {            
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {'Company_MyModule/js/swatch-renderer-mixin': true},
        },                
    }         
};
```

**Step 2)** 
Create the JS mixin file **swatch-renderer-mixin.js** under *app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js*

***File : app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer-mixin.js***

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';
         var mixin = {         
         _OnClick: function ($this, $widget) {
             //Start Write you Code here for Conf option Click event
             var myDuv = '<div style="width:100%; border:1px solid #95a5a6;padding:10px 0 10px 0;"><center>An option Clicked!.</center></div>';
             $(".product-add-form").prepend(myDuv);
             console.log("========= Config Option OnClick ====================");
             //End you code
             return this._super($this, $widget);
        },
         _OnChange: function ($this, $widget) { 
             //Start Write you Code here for Conf option Change event
             var myDuv = '<div style="width:100%; border:1px solid #95a5a6;padding:10px 0 10px 0;"><center>An option Change!.</center></div>';
             $(".product-add-form").prepend(myDuv);
             console.log("========= Config Option Change ====================");
             //End you code
            return this._super($this, $widget);
         }
    };

    return function (targetWidget) {        
        $.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer', targetWidget, mixin);
        return $.mage.SwatchRenderer;
    };
});
```

**step 3)** 
Clean Magento cache

```
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
```

=========== Demo ==============

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can directly select the options by url -

https://domain.com/test8.html#319=662&322=685

https://domain.com/test8.html#super_attribute1=option-value&super_attribute2=option-value

So you can use that concept and implement.